# How can i convert png image to binary 0 1 in python

Tags: python, image, binary-image

**Hello everyone how can i convert image to binary 0 and 1 like this :**

**give the image and convert it like this :**

```
11111111111111111111111111
11111100111111111100111111
11110001111100111110001111
11000001111000011110000011
10000000111000011100000001
10000000000000000000000001
00000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000
10000000000000000000000001
10000110001000010001100001
11001111111100111111110011
11100111111100111111100111
11111111111111111111111111
```

**without using opencv**

Comment: You will need some kind of library to read the image, if not `opencv` then something else.  It's too complex to do on your own.

Comment: Unfortunately  i can use only numpy and pil

Comment: Well PIL is exactly the "some kind of library" I was referring to.

Comment: Is your image already consisting of only black and white, or do you need to convert it?

Comment: I need to convert it  the image are playing card i should know the color the shape and the number

Comment: For the color i found a solution but for the shape and the number i had an idea to convert them to binary then store them in a list of matrice and compare them with the inserted image (converted to binary as well)